# swapping condition in "if" statement

Tags: java, if-statement, null

Consider this code snippet

```
import java.util.Date;

  class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    Date date = null;

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(date == null) {
        System.out.println("null == date");
    }else {
        System.out.println("date found "+date);
    }

      long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
      System.out.println(elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

In **if** condition I used **date==null** I wanted to know is there there any reduction in time complexity or vice versa if I choose to write **null==date**

PS- for both the condition my code is producing output as **0** but what if the code is complex and has heavy operations ?

Comment: I don't think it would make any difference

Comment: It won't make any difference.

Comment: @aKilleR This question is specifically ask about performance.

Comment: It also will not make any difference with regard to performance.

Answer (score 1):

`date == null` and `null == date` is almost exact equivalent.

In your specific case there no difference between them neither in speed nor in observed behavior.

You got `0` because modern computer is really fast and it is took less then millisecond to perform that calculation.

**PS:** If you really want to measure how long does it take you have to execute it hundreds of thousands times and divide measured time to count of execution.

**PPS:** Micro benchmark is not that easy in Java because you have take a lot of things into account, like JVM internal behavior, compiler optimization, GC, JIT and maybe something more.

**EDIT**
I was wrong they are complete equivalent because this code will be compiled to use `IFNONNULL` instruction.

Comment: It makes no difference until introducing multiple conditions. which then can be short-circuited. But i'm guessing that's not belonging to this question